# build golang compiler from the source using github actions

Tags: go, github-actions

I'm new to golang and I just wanted to build the golang compiler myself, specially for windows using the github actions. So, I wrote some codes, but all of them failed.
here are some of the things I tried so far:

#### Try 1

```
name: Build Go with MinGW

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install MinGW/MSYS
      run: |
        # Check if the file exists and is not corrupted
        if [ -f mingw-get-inst.exe ]; then
          # Run the installer
          ./mingw-get-inst.exe
        else
          echo "Error: mingw-get-inst.exe not found or corrupted."
          exit 1
        fi

    - name: Set up Go Environment
      run: |
        git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go
        cd go/src
        .\all.bat

    - name: Build 64-bit Go (if needed)
      if: matrix.goarch == 'amd64'
      run: |
        # Download and replace gcc.exe and ar.exe with their 64-bit counterparts.
        # Set GOARCH=amd64.
        # Perform 64-bit build steps.

    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        # Add commands to run your tests here.

    - name: Cleanup
      run: |
        # Add any cleanup steps here if needed.

    # Define matrix for 32-bit and 64-bit builds
    strategy:
      matrix:
        goarch: ['386', 'amd64']
```

#### Try 2

```
name: Build Go Compiler for Windows and Create Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest  # Use a Windows runner

    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install Git
      run: choco install git -y

    - name: Clone Go Repository
      run: |
        git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go C:\go
        cd C:\go\src
        git checkout goX.Y.Z  # Replace X.Y.Z with the version of Go you want to build

    - name: Build Go Compiler
      run: |
        cd C:\go\src
        all.bat

    - name: Set Go Environment
      run: |
        echo 'set PATH=C:\go\bin;%PATH%' >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\profile.bat

    - name: Verify Go Installation
      run: go version

    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      with:
        files: |
          C:\go\bin\*.exe  # Adjust the path and file pattern as needed
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      if: success()

    - name: Get Release URL
      id: get_release_url
      run: |
        echo "Release URL: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}"
      if: steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url
```

#### Try 3

```
name: Build Go Compiler for Windows and Create Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # Use a Linux runner

    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Clone Go Repository
      run: |
        git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go /usr/local/go
        cd /usr/local/go/src
        git checkout goX.Y.Z  # Replace X.Y.Z with the version of Go you want to build
      shell: bash

    - name: Build Go Compiler for Windows
      run: |
        cd /usr/local/go/src
        GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 ./all.bash
      shell: bash

    - name: Verify Go Installation
      run: |
        /usr/local/go/bin/go version
      shell: bash

    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      with:
        files: |
          /usr/local/go/bin/*  # Adjust the path and file pattern as needed
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      if: success()

    - name: Get Release URL
      id: get_release_url
      run: |
        echo "Release URL: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}"
      if: steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url
```

But each time it fails. Most of the time it fails at installing git and not able to clone the repo from https://go.googlesource.com/go
Any way to fix the yml?

Thanks

Edit: I've been trying to follow this to write the actions yml: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsBuild

Comment: Correctly installing git and pulling the source aside, it doesn't look like you are installing a bootstrap toolchain which is required.

Comment: "fails" how?  What errors or behaviours are you seeing that you don't expect? "it doesn't work" is rarely enough information for anyone to be able to help you.  Having said that, looking at the instructions you say you are following, installation of mingw appears to be interactive so will be difficult if not impossible to automate if going that route.  But beyond all this, why do you feel the need to build the compiler yourself at all?  imho you will learn Go more effectively by writing Go code, not building the compiler.

Comment: @Deltics I already mentioned that in the post that it fails mostly while installing git and while cloning repo from the url. & I actually wanted to build it myself, because I wanted to disable the "unused variable" error. Kinda like this: https://github.com/dtnewman/modified_golang_compiler
But this repo is old and most repos dont have windows installer

Comment: @xuka that's describing WHEN it fails, not HOW.  Is the one that fails on the clone the one that installs git (and fails?) or one of the others that doesn't?  Either way, what error do you get when attempting to clone?  If you don't understand how to properly explain a problem and are unwilling to provide clarification when asked then unfortunately you can't be helped.  That aside, the way to deal with unused variables is to write your code to avoid them.  That is easier (and better practice) than tweaking the compiler to allow bad code (clue: this is why such code is treated as an error).